# Problems with shutter speeds in landscape orientation with Canon New F-1

Tags: canon, troubleshooting, film, shutter

I use a Canon New F-1 and as long as I use it in portrait orientation all of the shutter speeds are working correctly. However,  as soon as I rotate the camera to landscape orientation it behaves just like in bulb mode no matter if I set it to a specific shutter speed or even use aperture priority.

Is there an obvious explanation to this behaviour and if so how do I set it up to work properly?

Comment: Sounds like a dodgy connection somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

New F1 and F1n get mixed up a lot, so I'm going to assume that you have the one with the hybrid shutter and the hotshoe on top of the prism.  Have you tried changing the shutter speed?  That camera has a hybrid shutter and some of the speeds are mechanical and some are electrical.  IIRC faster is mechanical.  Dodgy connection sounds right to me but I'm wondering if the mechanical speeds have the same problem.